# Error 500 when trying to run the ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to setup a basic CRUD API project in a new ASP.NET Core 6 Web API  project, but I get a http 500 error from Swagger.

`program.cs`:

```
using APICRUD.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddDbContext<BrandContext>(options => 
options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("conn")));

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Model

```
namespace APICRUD.Models
{
    public class Brand
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string? Name { get; set; }
        public string? Category { get; set; }
        public int IsActive { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
using APICRUD.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace APICRUD.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class BrandController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly BrandContext _dbContext;

        public BrandController(BrandContext dbContext)
        {
            _dbContext = dbContext;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Brand>>> GetBrands()
        {
            if (_dbContext.Brands == null) 
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return await _dbContext.Brands.ToListAsync();
        }

        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Brand>> GetBrand(int id)
        {
            if (_dbContext.Brands == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var brand = await _dbContext.Brands.FindAsync(id);

            if (brand == null) 
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return brand;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Brand>> PostBrand(Brand brand)
        {
            _dbContext.Brands.Add(brand);
            await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

            return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetBrand), new { id = brand.ID }, brand);
        }

        [HttpPut]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PutBrand(int id, Brand brand)
        {
            if (id != brand.ID)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            _dbContext.Entry(brand).State = EntityState.Modified;

            try
            {
                await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!BrandAvailable(id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return Ok();
        }

        public bool BrandAvailable(int id)
        {
            return (_dbContext.Brands?.Any(x => x.ID == id)).GetValueOrDefault();
        }

        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteBrand(int id)
        {
            if (_dbContext.Brands == null)
            {
                return NotFound();

            }
            var brand = await _dbContext.Brands.FindAsync(id);
            if (brand == null)
            {
                return NotFound();

            }
            _dbContext.Brands.Remove(brand);
            await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

            return Ok();

        }

    }
}
```

`[HttpGet]`, `[HttpPost]` and `[HttpGet("{id}")]` methods work fine. But when I try to add a new entry with `[HttpPut]` or delete an entry with `[HttpDelete("{id}")]`, an error pops up.

I'm thankful if you can help me out to find the mistake I made in this code.

Comment: Why don"t you put a break point in the `DeleteBrand()` method and see what is going on?

Answer (score 1):

There is an error of 500 for the internal server error.
use this code for display errors:

```
app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage()
```

Go to Microsoft Reference. [Handle errors in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-7.0&viewFallbackFrom=aspnetcore-2.2)

In the Web API, specify how the methods receive information. for example: [FromBody] or [FromHeader]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to put a forward slash in your http method?

```
[HttpDelete("/{id}")]
```